# ARP missing from the module scapy

Tags: python, scapy

i am trying to use scapy in python
while i try to import the scapy `import scapy`
its just fine but the line `scapy.ARP()` causes a

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ARP'

a `dir(scapy)` produces 
'`['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']'`
what might be the problem here ? do i need to install the packages separately if yes how to do it  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it , from the version v.2 onward the it should be used as from `scapy.all import *`